# Why is my PHP array merging all items into one?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have the following code

```
  <?php $data8 = $db->query("SELECT group_concat(distinct column_name) 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='tablename'")->fetch_assoc();
print_r($data8); ?>
```

This returns

```
Array ( [group_concat(distinct column_name)] => column1,column2,column3)
```

When then use

```
<?php 
$SavedNotes8= implode(" ",$data8);
print_r($SavedNotes8);
?>
```

it returns

```
column1,column2,column3
```

It appears as though all column names in the array are treated as a single item such that `implode` cannot detect the commas delimiting the separate items.

Why are they merged like this?

(Side question: How can I get rid of `[group_concat(distinct column_name)] =>` at the beginning of my array?)

Thanks!

Comment: you need to go though some tutorials, as this is basic sql knowledge you need to have

Comment: If you don't want the columns to be concatenated, then don't tell MySQL to concatenate them... simply use `SELECT column_name FROM ...`. Why did you put the `group_concat()` there in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson. I had tired that, but it only returns the first column name without group_concat()

Comment: If you only call `fetch_assoc()` once, then yes, you will only get one row. You need to iterate through the results. Please [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) what that command actually does and how you should use it, just as @cmorrissey suggested.

Comment: _implode cannot detect the commas delimiting the separate items._. This sounds like you want `explode` not `implode`, and you need to look for a comma, not a space `explode(',',$data8)`. But for this question it's better you follow @MagnusEriksson's advice about the SQL part. Just in case you need implode/explode later.

Comment: @jh1711 I originally decided to use `group_concat()` for exactly this reason; when I include the code `$SavedNotes8= explode(",",$data8);
print_r($SavedNotes8);`, however, nothing prints. Likewise, `var_dump($SavedNotes8);` returns `NULL`

Comment: @Snoops sorry my mistake. It should be `explode(",",$data8["group_concat(distinct column_name)"]);` or `explode(",",array_values($data8)[0]);`or if you use select ... as nice_name `explode(",",$data8['nice_name']);`

Comment: @jh1711 `explode(",",$data8["group_concat(distinct column_name)"]);` for some reason but `explode(",",array_values($data8)[0]);` did. I realize that this isn't a direct answer to my question, but you ended up solving my issue. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. The first part was again my mistake. I deleted the square brackets inside the string because they looked wrong. The correct command should be: `explode(",",$data8["[group_concat(distinct column_name)]"]);` . Anyhow I hope you don't postpone a proper solution  for to long. Don't use concat when you don't want to merge anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Mysql to turn those column names into a string through the concat command.

I would do something like this to get all column names:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='tablename';
```

You don't need to concatenate things in this situation.

---

Edit:

You also don't need to use "distinct" (as indicated by Magnus Eriksson) because column names in a table will always be unique.

Comment: You can lose `distinct` since column names in a table will always be unique.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think that far into it, I'll correct my answer accordingly.